# Do underwater acoustic waves create bubbles?

Tags: waves, acoustics, water, bubbles

I am working on a science fair project, and I currently need to develop a hypothesis. I am having a little trouble, but I have some ideas. I just need one answer so that I can go on about this. I would just like to know if when you put different frequency sound waves into water, do they create bubbles/air pockets?

EDIT: I have talked to some people, and have decided to talk about surface tension. No further comments or answers are necessary.

Comment: Do a google search on cavitation and sonoluminescence.

Answer (score 1):

for low intensity sound, bubbles are not formed. high intensity sound can form bubbles. Since the bubbles contain mostly water vapor, they quickly collapse after formation. you can learn more about this by searching for information on cavitation.